# How should I register my mongodb service that uses the MongoClient, Singleton or scoped?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am building an API with ASP.NET core using Mongodb and i have different services user service home service and etc. I would like to know should i register every service as singleton as it is mentioned in asp.net core documention or as scoped.  Link to repository https://github.com/krisk0su/apartments

UserService.cs

```
public class UserService
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<User> _books;
    private readonly IPasswordHasher _passwordService;

    public UserService(IBookstoreDatabaseSettings settings,  IPasswordHasher passwordService)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);

        _books = database.GetCollection<User>(settings.UsersCollectionName);
        _passwordService = passwordService;
    }

    public List<User> Get() =>
        _books
        .Find(book => true)
        .ToList();

    public User Get(string id) =>
        _books.Find(user => user.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    public User Create(User user)
    {
        var password = this._passwordService.HashPassword(user.Password);
        user.Password = password;
        _books.InsertOne(user);
        return user;
    }
    public void Update(string id, User bookIn) =>
        _books.ReplaceOne(book => book.Id == id, bookIn);

    public void Remove(User bookIn) =>
        _books.DeleteOne(book => book.Id == bookIn.Id);

    public void Remove(string id) =>
        _books.DeleteOne(book => book.Id == id);
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<UserService>();
            services.AddSingleton<BookService>();
            services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationService>();
            services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher, PasswordHasher>();
```

Comment: `service as singleton as it is mentioned in asp.net core documention` where did you see that? Short answer no, especially if you have db transactions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio . Here they register bookservice as singleton...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I not make my services singletons (ioc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123201/why-should-i-not-make-my-services-singletons-ioc)

Answer (score 22):

The [MongoDB .NET Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/) reference documentation for version 2.17 explains on the [Reference > Driver > Connecting](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/driver/connecting/) page in the Mongo Client [Re-use](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/driver/connecting#re-use) section that:

> It is recommended to store a [`MongoClient`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClient.htm) instance in a global place, either as a static variable or in an IoC container with a singleton lifetime.

With regards to Mongo Database [Re-use](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/driver/connecting/#re-use-1) it doesn't mention a singleton lifetime but it does say it "*is thread-safe and is safe to be stored globally*", so I would interpret that to mean it can be stored safely as a singleton if that's what your implementation desired, but it doesn't need to be if you prefer another lifetime.

> The implementation of [`IMongoDatabase`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoDatabase.htm) provided by a [`MongoClient`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClient.htm) is thread-safe and is safe to be stored globally or in an IoC container.

It's the same with regards to Mongo Collection [Re-use](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/driver/connecting/#re-use-2):

> The implementation of [`IMongoCollection<TDocument>`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1.htm) ultimately provided by a [`MongoClient`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClient.htm) is thread-safe and is safe to be stored globally or in an IoC container.

So again I'd interpret that to mean the choice of lifetime is up to your specific requirements.

It seems it's only the `MongoClient` that carries a *recommendation* to use a singleton lifetime.

Answer (score 14):

Well its complicated.

First of all `MongoClient` can be [singleton](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/getting_started/quick_tour/#mongoclient), so all services that uses `MongoClient` can be singletons as well. Its important cause singleton service cannot depends on service with shorter life (Scoped, Transient).

Now about `UserService`. All its dependancies is singletons and service itself don't stores any data (no fields, no props) that should live limited time or any data about particular user etc.

**So it can be singleton!**

But if you decided to add scoped dependancy or store any data in it:

```cs
public class UserService
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<User> users;
    private readonly long userCount; //this one

    public UserService(IBookstoreDatabaseSettings settings)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);

        users = database.GetCollection<User>(settings.UsersCollectionName);
        userCount = users.Find(_ => true).CountDocuments();
    }
}
```

then you have to make it at least Scoped.

---

Btw it's much easier to have `MongoClient` as singleton in DI:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(s => 
    new MongoClient(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDb"))
);
```

and then use it in all services:

```
public class UserService
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<User> users;

    public UserService(IMongoClient mongoClient)
    {
        var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("DatabaseName");
        users = database.GetCollection<User>(settings.UsersCollectionName);
    }
}
```

Or if you will use just one database in your app you can move IMongoDatabase to DI as well and then you don’t need to get it every time in the service constructor.

Comment: Scoped is quite useful if you're handling multi-doc transations and dont want a direct dependecy in IClientSessionHandle.